# Ruby GServer performance

Tags: ruby, performance

I tested the performance of GServer by implementing the most basic server and checked how many requests per second it could handle. The result was 81. This is very slow compared to the 9900 requests per second that my most basic TCPSocket server can handle. Am I doing something wrong or is GServer really this slow?

Client  implementation:

```
require 'socket'
tStart = Time.now
u = 0
while Time.now - tStart<5
    socket = TCPSocket.open('localhost', 1234)
    socket.puts 'a'
    socket.gets
    socket.close
    u += 1
end
puts u.to_s
```

GServer implementation:

```
require 'gserver'
class JServer < GServer
    def initialize(*args)
        super(*args)
    end

    def serve( io )
        io.gets
        io.puts( 'a' )
    end
end
server = JServer.new(1234)
server.start
loop { break if server.stopped? }
```

TCPSocket server implementaion:

```
require 'socket'
server = TCPServer.open(1234)
loop {
    client = server.accept
    puts client.gets
    client.puts( 'a' )
    client.close
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should get a significant speedup (approximately 30x from my testing) by replacing

> loop { break if server.stopped? }

with

> server.join

That being said, GServer uses threads and will probably be slower than a single-threaded event-based server.